# Pressing Esc is not firing KeyDown event

Tags: c#, forms, keydown

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> is not firing the `KeyDown` event. Pressing <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> fires the event but <kbd>Esc</kbd>does not.

What may be the reason?

`KeyPreview` is set to `True` in the following example:

```
    private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Space:
                btnCreate_Click(null, null); break;
            case Keys.F:
                switchThrow(); break;
            case Keys.Escape:
                form_FormClosing(null, null); break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of this code? Why is the code calling the *event handlers* of other controls instead of methods? In any case the `ESC` key has a very specific job - cancel and close the form. Submitting it is the job of `Enter`. This code can result in a lot of confusion in end users *and* the form code itself

Comment: Instead of clicking on Close button with the mouse, we just want to be able to close the form by pressing Esc, that's the point of the code. Called event handler methods are doing what the case needs so I called them directly, but I should define contents of them as a separate method I know.

Comment: You can already do that if you configure the form properly, as `Esc` is the keystroke for Cancel, the same way `Enter` is the keystroke for `OK`

Comment: Check [How to: Designate a Windows Forms Button as the Cancel Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-designate-a-windows-forms-button-as-the-cancel-button?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=On%20any%20Windows%20Form%2C%20you,the%20form%20has%20the%20focus.) and the same [using the designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/designate-a-wf-button-as-the-cancel-button-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Also [How to: Designate a Windows Forms Button as the Accept Button Using the Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/designate-a-wf-button-as-the-accept-button-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which by default will use ENTER as the Accept button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that, but weirdly after adding the Cancel button and defining it as a CancelButton to form pressing Esc is not firing the btnCancel_Click method and it is linked to the button's Click event. I guess I am using the wrong event handler, KeyPress and PreviewKeyDown events didn't help either.

Comment: " A cancel button is clicked whenever the user presses the ESC key" says in the document so the Click event should work.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense. Check the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netcore-3.1

> Certain keys, such as the <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and `arrow` keys are handled by controls automatically. To have these keys raise the KeyDown event, you must override the `IsInputKey` method in each control on your form.

```
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
    }
```

> Instead of overriding the `IsInputKey` method, you can handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event and set the `IsInputKey` property to true. For a code example, see the PreviewKeyDown event.

```
button1.PreviewKeyDown +=new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(button1_PreviewKeyDown);
```

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Escape:
            e.IsInputKey = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: TAB, RETURN, arrow keys are firing the event without defining them as an inputKey programmatically.

Comment: This seems weird, based on the documentation. Did it solve the problem with the Escape button?

Comment: I tried both IsInputKey and PreviewKeyDown methods but didn't work for Esc, unfortunately, thanks for the recommendation! I found ProcessCmdKey method on another post but it didn't help either.

Comment: I guess I am going to use "Q" for quitting